# Where to put holding loops

Tags: edges

[image]I'm just making a load of shapes at the moment, figuring things out. I'm having trouble with one shape, I can't figure out where to put holding loops in order to hold this plus[image], but also not distort the overall shape of the cylinder. What I want is closer to the mesh without the subdivision, but with the subdivision it obviously smooths it out a lot

Thanks, appreciate any advice

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You either need more geometry, or be resourceful with what little you have :)
Just for fun, I sticked with your 12 sided circle.

The geometry is still all quads, and you can easily sharpen the corners without disturbing the outside circle.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jachym, this was really helpful, really appreciate you taking the time on this, solved my problem perfectly, thanks everyone

Comment: Happy to help :). Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 3):

You can add crease to the plus sign part:

[image]

---

Complement, the initial shared file had an extrusion from the plus sign borders. Wihtout this extrusion, you can crease the vertices:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Lemon, I thought that might be the case but I'm not getting any change with the mean crease, it looks the same — I've added another pic to the question to show what I mean

Comment: ok, it's because the file you shared had an extrude part... I'll complete the answer in a moment...